# Copy line with search value from another file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use Python to:

1. Read a line from `search_list` file.
2. Iterate through `source_file` lines.
3. If a line match is found, copy that whole line from `source_file` to `export_file`.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until `search_file` is exhausted.

The contents of `source_file` are plain text. Sample:

```
Act of Heroism  Instant 1W  Common  Magali Villeneuve
Adorned Pouncer Creature — Cat 1/1  1W  Rare    Slawomir Maniak
Angel of Condemnation   Creature — Angel 3/3    2WW Rare    Slawomir Maniak
```

The `search_list` file is also a plain text with keywords, one per line, as in the following example:

```
Condemnation
Heroism
```

After spending some time in Stackoverflow, I have the current code --which is unusable at the moment:

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as search_list, \
        open('source_file.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as source_file:

    for line in search_list:
        searchquery = search_list.readlines()

        for line in source_file:
            current_line = line.split()

            if searchquery in current_line:
                print (line)
```

it returns nothing.

I try to figure it out what's wrong and so far I can't find it.

I did a step back and tried to search with string and it worked!

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as search_list, \
        open('source_file.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as source_file:

    for line in source_file:        
        if "Heroism" in line:
            print (line)
```

The result is:

```
Act of Heroism  Instant 1W  Common  Magali Villeneuve
```

Could anyone point me out what's wrong in my top code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "but it return nothing": there is no line containing "Dutiful Servants" in the source file. So... what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like none of the line matched "Dutiful Servants" string

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, it behaves as it should, none of the 3 lines from _source\_file.txt_ contains the string "_Dutiful Servants_", so nothing gets printed on the screen.

Comment: ouch. I trimmed the source file to make it short. I will update my code to match the current example source file. sorry for confuse everyone. :'(

Comment: Most likely, it's the __end of line__ (_eoln_). For example, the 1st line of _list.txt_ is "*Condemnation\n*", which doesn't exist in any of the _source\_file.txt_ lines (including "_Angel of **Condemnation** Creature — Angel 3/3 2WW Rare Slawomir Maniak_"). To get rid of this, after reading a line call `strip()` on it. Another __big__ problem in your code is: `if searchquery in current_line:`; `searchquery` is a list of strings, so is `current_line`; so the condition will never be `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpreted your question as that you want to output each line of a file `source_file.txt` that contains a certain substring, and these substrings are in another file `search_list.txt`. If that is correct, the following code should work for you:

```
import sys

with open('search_list.txt', 'r') as search_list:
    targets = [line.strip() for line in search_list]

with open('source_file.txt', 'r') as source_file:
    for line in source_file:
        if any(target in line for target in targets):
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

where `search_lines.txt` is

```
Condemnation
Heroism
```

and `source_file.txt` is

```
Act of Heroism Instant 1W Common Magali Villeneuve
Adorned Pouncer Creature — Cat 1/1 1W Rare Slawomir Maniak
Angel of Condemnation Creature — Angel 3/3 2WW Rare Slawomir Maniak
```

this will correctly output

```
Act of Heroism Instant 1W Common Magali Villeneuve
Angel of Condemnation Creature — Angel 3/3 2WW Rare Slawomir Maniak
```

which is each line that contains either '`Condemnation`' or '`Heroism`'.

This works by first building up a list of all the `targets` first, and then for each line in `source_file.txt`, checking if any target is a substring of the line. You have to build up the list of targets as when you iterate over a file in Python each line is 'consumed' so you can't go back to the start again in another for loop.

The way the line `if any(target in line for target in targets)` works is broadly like this:

First, it uses the generator expression `target in line for target in targets`. This returns the value of `target in line` (which checks if `target` is a substring of `line`) for each `target` in `targets` - it could also effectively be written as

```
with open('source_file.txt', 'r') as source_file:
    for line in source_file:
        matches = []
        for target in targets:
            matches.append(target in line)
        if any(matches):
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Now, the `any` function takes an iterable (something like a list) and returns `True` if any of the values are `True` (or equivalent to `True`). It also has the property of short-circuiting - it actuallly stops as soon as it does meet `True`, if it does. This means the code could be rewritten pretty accuately as

```
with open('source_file.txt', 'r') as source_file:
    for line in source_file:
        matches = []
        for target in targets:
            if target in line:
                sys.stdout.write(line)
                break
```

(This has to do with the fact that there is a generator expression, which does not evaluate the whole thing at once, but lazily gives one value at a time, meaning no more work will be done than needed.)

By the way, `[line.strip() for line in search_list]` is a list comprehension. This returns a list of `line.strip()` for each line in `search_list`. This could be rewritten as

```
    targets = []
    for line in search_list:
        targets.append(line.strip()
```

Hopefully that's helped. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is some useful documentation on how list comprehensions work. I find it can often be useful to start with the simpler examples like `[i ** 2 for i in range(10)]`. Let me know if you'd like any more clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked! I saw output on screen as I expected. I will try to write the output to the file. 

what I learned are; 1) I need to use line.strip() I guess it will strip all content into list but will google for that. 2) I do not understand "any(target in line for targets in targets)". Is this called list comprehension? I need to study that asap.